# Can we have "network wide" maintenance message?

Tags: feature-request, maintenance

Can we have a "network wide" maintenance message for Stack Exchange family sites (and sub sites like [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/)) to avoid cases like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122810/system-message-about-db-maintenance-on-facebook-stackoverflow-com) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/maintenance-message-still-shown-of-facebook-stackoverflow-com).

It'll be also great if such a message had a link to blog post (if any) describing upcoming maintenance.

Currently such messages looks like:

> We'll be doing some network maintenance today starting around 2PM UTC. The site may go up and down while we shuffle things around.

Or:

> In just a bit, Stack Overflow will be offline for 30 minutes while we give our database hardware some love.

Both of those have strong issue with time specified for maintenance since there is no date in the message, in case such message wasn't removed it confuse people a lot.

Comment: We didn't link to the blog post because it was *network maintenance*, and while we went offline...so did all the blogs.  In every case where the blogs would still be up, we already do link to them.

Comment: @NickCraver, At the time of maintenance yes. But I had time to read that message before maintenance started, so the link was probably useful for me at that time (and for sure it'll be even more useful in cases message wasn't removed for some reason).

Comment: You're not saying [even chat was offline](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2012/02/15/planning-for-failure/), are you Nick? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - different network, only the blog.se and blog.so instances live with chat, blog.sf (and all others) are in NYC where we quite literally yanked the cables connecting us to the internet out of the racks at one point.

Comment: You yanked *all* cables? I have a hard time [believing that](http://serverfault.com/404). ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - how the hell did you get in our data center to snap that??